# Displaying Viewcontroller based on Notification payload swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, rx-swift

I am getting a push notification and displaying a viewcontroller based on the content of the notification.When the notification is triggered manually from postman, I get the following `userInfo`

```
    [AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.type"): new_property, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.meta"): {"property_id":"3"}, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1570614460795417, AnyHashable("aps"): {
        alert =     {
            body = "A new property has been published is in your area";
            title = "New Property";
        };
    }]
// CASTING AS [String: Any]
    ["google.c.a.e": 1, "gcm.notification.meta": {"property_id":"3"}, "gcm.notification.type": new_property, "aps": {
        alert =     {
            body = "A new property has been published is in your area";
            title = "New Property";
        };
    }, "gcm.message_id": 1570614460795417]
```

This in turn works and displays the required screen. But when ever a user action triggers the same notification, I get this `userInfo`

```
    [AnyHashable("gcm.notification.meta"): {"property_id":46}, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.type"): new_property, AnyHashable("body"): A new property has just been listed in your area by Ebenezer Kilani, AnyHashable("title"): New property Listing, AnyHashable("type"): new_property, AnyHashable("meta"): {"property_id":46}, AnyHashable("aps"): {
        alert =     {
            body = "A new property has just been listed in your area by Ebenezer Kilani";
            title = "New property Listing";
        };
    }, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1570550088749025, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1]
// CASTING AS [String: Any]
    ["meta": {"property_id":46}, "type": new_property, "title": New property Listing, "gcm.message_id": 1570550088749025, "gcm.notification.meta": {"property_id":46}, "body": A new property has just been listed in your area by Ebenezer Kilani, "aps": {
        alert =     {
            body = "A new property has just been listed in your area by Ebenezer Kilani";
            title = "New property Listing";
        };
    }, "google.c.a.e": 1, "gcm.notification.type": new_property]
```

the second payload just opens the application but never goes into the view controller I need it to. That is, it opens the home page only.

How I am getting the userInfo

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let usrInfo = userInfo as? [String: Any] {
            extractUserInfo(userInfo: usrInfo, completion: completionHandler)
        }
        completionHandler()
    }

func extractUserInfo(userInfo: [String: Any], completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

        if let type = userInfo["gcm.notification.type"] as? String {
                    Storage.instance.savePush(type)
                    if type == "new_property" {
                        if let meta = userInfo["gcm.notification.meta"] as? String {

                            if let data = meta.data(using: .utf8) {

                                do {
                                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {
                                        guard let propertyId = json["property_id"] as? String, let id = Int(propertyId) else {return}
                                        NotificationEvent.isFromNotification.accept(true)
                                        NotificationEvent.id.accept(id)

                                    } else {
                                        print("JSON is invalid")
                                    }
                                } catch {
                                    print("Exception converting: \(error)")
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } 
       }
 }
```

how I handle the push to display required Viewcontroller

```
class Remote {

    var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    @discardableResult
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController?) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
        rxEvent()
    }

    func rxEvent() {

        NotificationEvent.isFromNotification.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { bool in
            print("Exception converting: bool \(bool)")
            if bool {
                NotificationEvent.id.asObservable()
                    .delay(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                    .subscribe(onNext: { int in
                    if int > 0 {
                        if Storage.instance.getPush() == "new_property" {
                            self.presentPropertyDetailVC(int)
                        } else if Storage.instance.getPush() == "new_rating" || Storage.instance.getPush() == "coverage_area" {
                            print(int)
                        }
                    }
                }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
                NotificationEvent.isFromNotification.accept(false)
            }
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    func presentPropertyDetailVC(_ uid: Int) {
        //        navigationVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        let controller = PropertyDetailVC()
        controller.propertyId = uid
        print("Exception converting: 11 \(controller)")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

then I instantiate `Remote` in my home VC

Any reason why the first payload work and the second does not and anything I could do to correct that.

Comment: The second one, when cast as `String: Any`, appears to have `type`, not `gcm.notification.type`

Comment: @Scriptable it does. it has it too `"gcm.notification.type"`

Comment: oh i see there is `type` *and* `gcm.notification.type` Can you set some breakpoints and step through it?

Comment: `if let meta = userInfo["gcm.notification.meta"] as? String {` is not `String` in the second example, no? To debug, when you do a `if let`, please do the else to print that it failed

Comment: This line  
guard let propertyId = json["property_id"] as? String, let id = Int(propertyId) else {return}
is getting to the "return" because on the second meta 46 is an int not a string (note that it have not quotes. 
To fix it you can try

guard let propertyId = json["property_id"] as? String ?? String(json["property_id"] as? Int ?? 0), let id = Int(propertyId) else {return}

Comment: @NoelCarcases add as answer so I can mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
guard let propertyId = json["property_id"] as? String, let id = Int(propertyId) else {return}
```

is getting to the "return" because on the second meta 46 is an int not a string (note that it have not quotes. To fix it you can try

```
guard let propertyId = json["property_id"] as? String ?? String(json["property_id"] as? Int ?? 0), let id = Int(propertyId) else {return}
```